# MQTT malformed packet

Tags: docker, mqtt, docker-network, malformed

Running mosquito broker in docker, broker ip address is 172.18.5.10, docker network gateway is 172.18.5.1. There are also some other dockers attached to that network, also I do have several MQTT devices / programs subscribed and publishing to Mosquito broker and working just fine.

The issues is I am getting following error every ~ 40 seconds.

```
2023/02/22T14:20:09: New connection from 172.18.5.1:47008 on port 1883.
2023/02/22T14:20:09: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
2023/02/22T14:20:37: New connection from 172.18.5.1:47162 on port 1883.
2023/02/22T14:20:37: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
2023/02/22T14:21:05: New connection from 172.18.5.1:47270 on port 1883.
2023/02/22T14:21:05: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
2023/02/22T14:21:33: New connection from 172.18.5.1:47418 on port 1883.
2023/02/22T14:21:33: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
2023/02/22T14:22:01: New connection from 172.18.5.1:47538 on port 1883.
2023/02/22T14:22:01: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
2023/02/22T14:22:29: New connection from 172.18.5.1:47674 on port 1883.
2023/02/22T14:22:29: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
2023/02/22T14:22:57: New connection from 172.18.5.1:47782 on port 1883.
```

Here is result from wireshark for

```
2023/02/22T14:21:05: New connection from 172.18.5.1:47270 on port 1883.
2023/02/22T14:21:05: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
```

[image]

More detailed error image for different src port

[image]

Here is an example of good and bad connections, good connection are from local IP address range but this malformed is always from network gateway:

```
2023/02/21T22:38:03: New client connected from 192.168.3.8:52207 as sw-tasmota-hall (p2, c1, k30, u'data').
2023/02/21T22:38:04: New connection from 192.168.3.1:57113 on port 1883.
2023/02/21T22:38:04: New client connected from 192.168.3.1:57113 as switch-tasmota-bath (p2, c1, k30, u'data').
2023/02/21T22:38:04: New connection from 192.168.2.4:58631 on port 1883.
2023/02/21T22:38:04: New client connected from 192.168.2.4:58631 as node-tasmota-garage (p2, c1, k30, u'data').
2023/02/21T22:38:06: New connection from 172.18.5.1:48908 on port 1883.
2023/02/21T22:38:06: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
2023/02/21T22:38:28: New connection from 172.18.5.1:49018 on port 1883.
2023/02/21T22:38:28: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
2023/02/21T22:38:50: New connection from 172.18.5.1:49160 on port 1883.
2023/02/21T22:38:50: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.15
    container_name: mosquitto
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Prague
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
    volumes:
      - /share/Container/mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - /share/Container/mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config
      - /share/Container/mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro      
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://192.168.1.106:514"
        tag: "{{.Name}}/{{.ImageName}}"
    networks:
      ha_net:
         ipv4_address: 172.18.5.10
networks:
  ha_net:
    external: true
```

mosquitto.conf

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
persistence_file mosquitto.db

listener 1883

allow_anonymous true

log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
log_dest stdout
log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format %Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S

password_file /mosquitto/config/pwfile
```

I am looking for help how to detect ip address of the device/host/program that is causing this issue.

Thanks,
salvq

Comment: The wireshark output is clearly a HTTP GET request, first thought is it a bad Health Check? Are you running the official eclipse mosquitto container or something you have created yourself?

Comment: Running official docker, 'image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.15'

Comment: No obvious HTTP Health Check configured, I would scroll down in the wireshark capture more to see if there is a UserAgent in the HTTP request that would help narrow it down. But it's 100% a HTTP client making a get request to the exposed port. Probably on the Docker host machine (guessing based on the IP address)

Comment: I uploaded one more picture showing UserAgent like you assumed, does it mean it comes from host machine ? Besides docker containers ? I tried to turn off all the containers on host but still getting these errors.

Comment: It tells you it's a python application nothing more, the assumption (a guess as I said earlier) it came from the host is because the first address in a docker custom network is normally assigned to the docker host machine. That is all that can be said so far, you are in the best position to know what it running where in your environment

Comment: I am not able to find the app, it seems to me like mosquito itself. Now I tried to run mosquito container as host (not part of bridge docker network) and there are no errors like `2023/02/21T22:38:06: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet`. This is really strange where is the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue (disconnects due to malformed packet) by running mosquito docker in HOST network mode rather than custom bridge network mode.

However, I have not been able to determine the root cause of the disconnects due to malformed packet on the docker custom bridge network, but not in host network mode.

Working docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.15
    container_name: mosquitto
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Prague
    volumes:
      - /share/Container/mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - /share/Container/mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config
      - /share/Container/mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro      
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://192.168.1.106:514"
        tag: "{{.Name}}/{{.ImageName}}"
```

Comment: This is not a real solution, somewhere on your environment there is still a python application making HTTP requests to the old network address.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue but the case happens on esp32 with pubsubclient. the main problem is caused by my device has same id connected to broker  on multiple devices. make sure every connection that you generate has a unique id.

Comment: Clashing client ids will not cause the error shown in the question, the broker will explicitly log that the earlier client was disconnected, not "malformed packet" errors